# "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE" when trying to put an image in snake game

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I coded a fully functional snake game. I used an arc to draw the apple but I wanted to change this and put an image of an apple. Now it's not working and I receive the following error: `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:`

Can someone explain to me where is my mistake and how to fix it? :/
Thank you :)
PS: Sorry for my English, I'm Belgian ;)

The full working code is here:
https://codepen.io/graphtylove/pen/MZXegG

```
    function Apple(position) {
        this.position = position;
        this.draw = function() {
          const radius = blockSize / 2;
          const x = this.position[0] * blockSize + radius;
          const y = this.position[1] * blockSize + radius;
          ctx.save();
          ctx.drawImage(foodImg,x,y );
          ctx.restore();
        };

        this.setNewPosition = function() {
          const newX = Math.round(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 1));
          const newY = Math.round(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 1));
          this.position = [newX, newY];
        };
        this.isOnSnake = function(snakeToCheck) {
          let isOnSnake = false;

          for (let i = 0; i < snakeToCheck.body.length; i++) {
            if (
              this.position[0] === snakeToCheck.body[i][0] &&
              this.position[1] === snakeToCheck.body[i][1]
            ) {
              isOnSnake = true;
            }
          }
          return isOnSnake;
        };
      }
```

I want to have the image of the apple instead of the red circle I actually have. But when I change the code, the game crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses various external files, and they don't work on codepen. If codepen is what you're trying to use to create your website, then external files won't work, unless it's from a URL, such as google.com/javascriptfile.js. If you are using Notepad++, Notepad, or something else that you downloaded, then files from your computer might work. For example, `<img src='myFiles/myImage.png'>` will not work on codepen and similar websites. However, Notepad++ and similar applications will find the file, if the folder "myFiles" is in the same folder as your .html file. Instead, while using codepen and similar websites, you must a URL. You can upload your picture/script to a website and then use the file inside the website. This also applies to the `<script>` tag, and other tags that use `src=`. If this makes no sense, just tell me in the comments! If it helps, please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: I'm not using codepen. That was for give you the code but i use visual studio code. All my external files work fine. The apple is the problem. If i use it as a arc() function it work. But when i try to use drawImages() the game don't work anymore. That's the point :/